# BufferedReader.readLine() method Blocking alternative

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, network-protocols

Is there any way to make the method readline() (from bufferedReader) block until it has in fact something to read??

I'm creating an client/server application socketBased and I have this

The **Server** reads and then writes. The **Client** writes and then reads.. this is the communication between client/server (based on sockets)

The only problem is that on the server I'm reading with bufferedReader.readLine() which isn't a blocking method. I have already tried replacing the bufferedReader.readLine() by dataInputstream().read() (handle all the byte stuffs and getting out when -1 is received) and  it isn't working either.

The problem in all this is that the server is expecting to read but do not blocks. the client is only going to write to the server (through a socket) when the user press a button (so the server must be waiting for reading and it is not)

On the **server** side i have this:

```
    BufferedReader READ = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter WRITE = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(skt.getOutputStream()));
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);

        boolean FLAG = true;

        String s = new String("#$");

        while (FLAG) {


            if (skt == null)
                FLAG = false;

            // READING FROM THE CLIENT
            while (!READ.ready()){System.out.println("Blocking")};

            while ((s = READ.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("RECEIVING: " + s);
                System.out.println("$$$");
            }

            System.out.print("hi");
            // READING FROM THE FILE AND SENDING TO THE CLIENT
            //WRITTING TO THE CLIENT
            while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("SENDING: " + strLine);
                strLine += "\n";
                WRITE.write(strLine);
                WRITE.flush();
                strLine = new String();
            }
        }
```

On the **Client** side i have this:

```
    //READING FROM THE FILE AND SENDING TO THE SERVER
                 while((strLine  = in.readLine()) != null)  
                 {  

                        strLine += "\n";


                        soma+=strLine.length();
                        WRITE.write(strLine);
                        WRITE.flush();

                        TextArea1.append(strLine);
                        ProgressBar.setValue(soma);
                        ProgressBar.repaint();  

                    };          
                    in.close();


                    ProgressBar.setValue(0);
                    soma=0;

                    //READING FROM THE SERVER
                    while((strLine=READ.readLine()) != null)
                    {

                        strLine+="\n";
                        soma+=strLine.length();

                        TextArea2.append(strLine);
                        strLine = new String();
                        ProgressBar.setValue(soma);
                        ProgressBar.repaint();  
                    }

                    in.close();
                    fstream.close();
                    WRITE.close();
                    READ.close();

                    Skt.close();
```

**NOTE:**  Skt is a socket connecting client to server.

the problem here is that. When the client connects to the server, the server expects to read from the socket right after the connection is established.. however the code on the client (writing to the server) is only expected to run when the user presses a button.. So, the server must be blocked until the client in fact writes something to the socket which is not (the server is not blocking). :-/ hope to make my self more clear this time.. Sorry

Comment: i corrected your formatting ;)

Comment: What you are asking for is exactly what it does. It is a blocking method. Not a real question. I suggest you post your *problem,*, not what you misconceive the solution to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BufferedReader.readLine() always blocks until it finds `'\n'`.

If you can give examples of data you're sending around, I might help you further.

Comment: well i'm sending words (from a dictionary file) through the socket.. i have already tried another format and i don't know why it does not block. If you want i can put some content of the file.. (it was just a simple dictionary, used because i just want to send some bytes over the network).

Comment: @PedroNeves It *does* block. Are you perhaps ignoring end of stream?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use file lock approach like:

```
file = new RandomAccessFile("file.txt", "rw");
FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
fl = channel.tryLock();
// file now is locked
fl.release();
```

Comment: does it helps on sockets?? I'll see ;)

Comment: Completely irrelevant. Not an answer.